# Is there any Delphi Keyboard Shortcuts to Switch the Cursor-Select between [Code Editor] and [Projects Window] of the Opened Source Code File?

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

While coding in Embarcadero Delphi RAD Studio IDE, I used to open multiple Source Code tabs on [Code Editor](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Code_Editor) Window from [Projects Window](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Projects_Window).
However I want to Toggle Between The Current Source Code tab and its Project folder for debug purpose etc.

I Tried with `[Ctrl+Alt+F11]` :  But it will navigate to a previously selected File(Instead of Current File of Editor) on Projects Window.